# Blender 2.79 screencast keys do not display rotation axis

Tags: interface

When I enter a command like R followed by an axis e.g. X, only the R is displayed by the screencast script. All of the other expected functionality is there. Is there a way to force the display of the axes?

Comment: The original Screencast keys addon is depreciated and one of the reasons is, it does not collect the events during a modal operation like Grab or Scale. But I found a completely new screencast keys addon that does capture everything. To install, download the zip file, give it nicer name than master.zip and use the blender addon "install from file..." button.  https://github.com/chromoly/blender-ScreencastKeysMod - drat! that url is dead. Maybe someone knows where it went.

Comment: Chromoly took down all their add-ons, author's decision. The only problem with open source scripts not being forked imo.